# Populating the UI from a text file - python

Tags: python, pyside

I broke my question down to a very basic setup. Each tab allows a user to click a button and append and item to the list. At the same time the item is added to the list, it's also added to a global variable called **ALLITEMs**. Each tab is given it's over dictionary to append to as seen here..

```
ALLITEMS = {
        "A" : [],
        "B" : []
    }
```

In the main widget on the '**closeEvent**' i save this variable to a json file. Also in the main widgets '**showEvent**' i load this data back into the global bariable **ALLITEMS**. This allows users to retain the data each time the launch the application. What I'm not sure about is how to refresh the tab widgets to repopulate the GUI's with the data from the variable. But only when the tool is initially launched. I don't want it to load each time the user clicks that tab, that would produce duplicate data.

[image]

```
import sys
import json
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

ALLITEMS = {
    "A" : [],
    "B" : []
}

# Widgets
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ExampleA(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleA, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        # formatting
        self.resize(550, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tab A")

        # widgets
        self.ui_listview = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.ui_add = QtGui.QPushButton("Add Item")

        # signals
        self.ui_add.clicked.connect(self.add_item_clicked)

        # main layout
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_add)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_listview)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def add_item_clicked(self):
        global ALLITEMS
        item = "Another item A"
        ALLITEMS["A"].append(item)
        self.ui_listview.addItem( item )


class ExampleB(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleB, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        # formatting
        self.resize(550, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tab A")

        # widgets
        self.ui_listview = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.ui_add = QtGui.QPushButton("Add Item")

        # signals
        self.ui_add.clicked.connect(self.add_item_clicked)

        # main layout
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_add)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_listview)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def add_item_clicked(self):
        global ALLITEMS
        item = "Another item B"
        ALLITEMS["B"].append(item)
        self.ui_listview.addItem( item )


class ExampleMain(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleMain, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        # formatting
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        # widgets
        tab_panel = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        tab_panel.addTab(ExampleA(), "Tab A")
        tab_panel.addTab(ExampleB(), "Tab B")

        # main layout
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(tab_panel)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_data()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.load_data()

    def save_data(self):
        print "Saving..."
        global ALLITEMS
        json.dump(ALLITEMS, open("Example_Data.json",'w'), indent=4)

    def load_data(self):
        global ALLITEMS
        if os.path.exists( "Example_Data.json" ):
            with open( "Example_Data.json" ) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                ALLITEMS = data

# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleMain()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the global variable entirely.

In your closeEvent, instead of saving the global variable, read the items from the listview directly and save them.  In your `add_item` method, don't modify the global variable at all.

Then in your load_data function, read the data from the file and add the items to the listviews.

You will need to store references to the ex.ample widgets

```
self.example_a = ExampleA()
self.example_b = ExampleB()

tab_panel.addTab(self.example_a), "Tab A")
tab_panel.addTab(self.example_b), "Tab B")
```

Here's how you could save and load the data:

```
def save_data(self):
    print "Saving..."
    all_items = {}
    for i in range(self.example_a.ui_listview.count()):
        text = self.example_a.ui_listview.item(i).text()
        all_items.set_default('A', []).append(text)
    for i in range(self.example_b.ui_listview.count()):
        text = self.example_b.ui_listview.item(i).text()
        all_items.set_default('B', []).append(text)
    json.dump(all_items, open("Example_Data.json",'w'), indent=4)

def load_data(self):
    if os.path.exists( "Example_Data.json" ):
        with open( "Example_Data.json" ) as f:
            all_items = json.load(f)
            for text in all_items.get('A', []):
                self.example_a.ui_listview.addItem(text)
            for text in all_items.get('B', []):
                self.example_b.ui_listview.addItem(text)
```

Also, in general, it's usually bad design for a parent widget to access grandchild widgets directly (ui_listview is a grandchild of your main widget `ExampleMain` class).  It's generally better form for your widgets to define some type of interface for portraying what they need saved and loaded.

```
class ExampleMain:

    def save_data(self):
        data = {}
        data['example_a'] = self.example_a.save_data()
        data['example_b'] = self.example_b.save_data()
        # Save to file

    def load_data(self):
        data = ... # read from file
        self.example_a.load_data(data.get('example_a'))
        self.example_b.load_data(data.get('example_b'))


class ExampleA:

    def save_data(self):
        data = []
        for i in range(self.ui_listview.count()):
            text = self.ui_listview.item(i).text()
            data.append(text)
        return data

    def load_data(self, data):
        for text in data:
            self.ui_listview.addItem(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest (although not very effective) way would be to update list widget from ALLITEMS dictionary each time you change it. So on every button press you could update ALLITEMS first, then clear the content of list widget and refill it according to new value of ALLITEMS["TabName"]. Then on show event you could do the same - load ALLITEMS from file **once** and then update list widget.

For more effective approach take a look at Qt Model/View programming (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) You will probably need to replace QListWidget with QListView

Comment: I looked into the model approach and there was a lack of examples and help whe posting on forums so I sadly resulted to more of the manual process of things. I'll check it out though thank you for the help.